# Black screen on slide-out menu VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm using the [SWViewController Library](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController). When implementing the library, my frontViewController shows up but my rearViewController is black. I don't know what's causing this issue and could use some help with it. The app is entirely programmed in Objective C. There is no swift and no storyboards with this app.

Here is my code for rearViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RearViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *rearTableView;

@end
```

rearViewController.m:

```
#import "RearViewController.h"

#import "SWRevealViewController.h"




@interface RearViewController()

{
    NSInteger _presentedRow;
}

@end

@implementation RearViewController

@synthesize rearTableView = _rearTableView;


#pragma mark - View lifecycle


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Rear View", nil);
}
```

my code for appDelegate.h:

```
@class SWRevealViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) TARootViewController  *rootViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SWRevealViewController *viewController;

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;


@end
```

and my code for appDelegate.m:

```
    #import "AppDelegate.h"

    #import "SWRevealViewController.h"
    #import "RearViewController.h"

    @interface AppDelegate()<SWRevealViewControllerDelegate>
    @end

    @implementation AppDelegate

    @synthesize window = _window;
    @synthesize viewController = _viewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window = window;
    RearViewController *rearViewController = [[RearViewController alloc] init];
    TARootViewController *frontViewController = [[TARootViewController alloc] init];
    SWRevealViewController *revealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc] initWithRearViewController:rearViewController frontViewController:frontViewController];
    revealController.delegate = self;

    self.window.rootViewController = revealController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


    if (self.rootViewController.activeViewController == nil) {
        [[TAActiveUserManager sharedManager] startOrResumeAppSession];
    }


    // Register device for push notifications
    UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                    UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |


    UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                             categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];

    return YES;
}

there is more here but it's not relevant to initializing the viewcontrollers
```

Comment: I'm debugging using breakpoints, and making a breakpoint in RearViewController.m before the viewDidLoad function ends returns a value that's not nil, which means the view does exist someplace in memory

Comment: It appears that there are some issues with the SWRevealController Library in this regard. A google search turned this out:

`Had the same issue. Setting revealAnimationType = SWRevealToggleAnimationTypeEaseOut fixes it but I liked SWRevealToggleAnimationTypeSpring better.`

Comment: This seems to be an outdated fix for an older version of the library. Changing the property in the list of default properties within the library did not fix this for me.

Comment: [link](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/issues/323) to the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this on reddit as well, and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/3fy53s/slideout_menu_is_black_need_help_to_make_it/) is the thread that answered my question.

It turns out that black is the default viewController color for SWRevealViewController - just because it's black doesn't mean that it's not loading properly.

Answer (score -1):

This has had happened to me before. The default background color for view controllers is clear. make sure you have your background or at least your window's background color set. In AppDelegate.m:

```
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Also, I'm assuming you want a navigation controller in their since your setting a view controllers self.title property. The title will show up in the Navigation bar when that particular view controller is on top of the stack. It is simple to imbed your view controller into a navigationController. Replace this with the line where you set your rootViewController.

```
self.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:revealController];
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! The instructions in the library and the examples are slightly different from what you posted, as I have to set SWRevealViewController as the root view controller for the library to work.

Also, where do I set the background color in appdelegate.m? How do I specify that it's for the slide out menu only? (the rest of the views load correctly) Apologies for any noob questions in advance - I'm very new to iOS coding. I went with C instead of Swift because I have some experience programming with it as opposed to not having any for Swift/Storyboards.

Comment: Just set it in the ViewDidLoad anywhere between the initialization of the window and makeKeyandVisible. I usually just do it right before `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]`. Yeah don't worry about the Navigation segment I said then. Also, each viewController has a .backgroundColor property so if you ever wanted to troubleshoot and see which viewController is currently on the stack just set each of them to a different color.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. Btw, in the library files the default background color is set to black - I thought it wasn't passing in the view correctly, but turns out that's exactly what it's supposed to do. Is there a way to turn it clear so that the content I want to write to it shows through? Or will content automatically appear on it if I add a table to the view controller?

Comment: For clear color set background color to `[UIColor clearColor]`, Content isn't going to appear if you add a tableView, It will show default cell rows that will just appear as little horizontal lines. For content to appear you will want to add that conent to the individual cells in a tableView after they have been instantiated in the cellForRowAtIndexPath protocol.

Comment: Figured out the answer to that question as well - if I set it to clear nothing will show up, so I set it to white in the library itself. Now I need to get the data onto the view controller >.>